# Исчезает весь текст с карты после инциализации

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Собственно после загрузки карты с нее плавно с таким fadeOut'ом исчезают все тексты, хотя карта подключена достаточно дефолтно

```js
async initilize () {
  try {
    await window.ymaps3.ready

    // Initialization
    this.map = new window.ymaps3.YMap(
      this.$refs.container,
      { location: { center: MOCK_POSITION, zoom: ZOOM } }
    )

    // Layers
    this.map.addChild(new window.ymaps3.YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({}))
    this.map.addChild(new window.ymaps3.YMapFeatureDataSource({ id: MARKER_SOURCE, zIndex: 1000 }))
    this.map.addChild(new window.ymaps3.YMapLayer({ source: MARKER_SOURCE, type: 'markers', zIndex: 1800 }))

    // Points
    if (markers?.length) {
      markers.forEach((_marker, index) => {
        this.map.addChild(
          this.getMarker(_marker, index)
        )
      })
    }

    this.loading = false
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Произошла ошибка инициализации карты', error)
  }
}

getMarker (marker, index) {
  const eventHandlerLink = this.onMarkerClick
  const id = `marker-${index}`
  const markerElement = document.createElement('div')
  markerElement.classList.add('p-map__marker')
  markerElement.innerHTML = markerIcons[marker.service]
  markerElement.id = id

  return new window.ymaps3.YMapMarker(
    {
      coordinates: [marker.lon, marker.lat],
      id,
      source: MARKER_SOURCE,
      onClick: () => eventHandlerLink(marker, id)
    },
    markerElement
  )
}
```

Ну и собственно карта после этого выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Забыл добавить, что данная проблема встречается только на хостинге, на локалхосте все ок

Comment: Если это происходит на конкретном хостинге, хорошо бы пример живой увидеть. Может там автоматом какие-то стили подтягиваются и ломают работу карты?

Comment: @YaCor' Так карта в канвасе, каким образом css может выборочно в канвасе выключить мне текста??

Comment: Если ситуацию видно только вам, едва ли кто сможет помочь. Приведите рабочий пример для проверки. Быть может, это вообще на вашей машине глюки с видеокартой какие. Будет доступный минимальный пример без текста — посмотрим.